# Automatically save a mail from Gmail to Google Drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive, automation, pdf

Every month I get approx 50 receipts for various things via email. I need to copy/print these to pdf (or similar) and store them in a receipt folder (eg. July 2018) on Google Drive. Currently, I do this manually, as every receipt is from a different provider etc. — so there is no easy matching element. I was thinking if I was to set up a filter in Gmail and have them tagged, "something" else could go through these tags and create PDFs (or similar) from these emails and place them in the correct folder.

Any suggestions about how I could do this?

Comment: Fair enough vote- I was really unsure where to put the question!

Answer (score 1):

this can be all automated on a scale that you don't need to lift a finger... all you need is spreadsheet and addon which will scan your Gmail inbox once per hour and it will backup all chosen (based on criterions you set) emails (in PDF) with all attachments and even place a label "saved" to your emails, that were backed up already so you can check the whole everything via Gmail or Drive.

- **addon:** **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc)**
- **video tutorial:** **[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfyfqM5Ww8k)**

Comment: Why did you revert the edit made by Alex?